# Patching a file in resulting rootfs

Tags: buildroot

I am using buildroot to create an OS for the Raspberry PI.
How do I apply a patch to a file in the resulting rootfs?

For example adding the lines

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp

to /etc/network/interfaces on the resulting rootfs.

I realize that this can be done with a script after unpacking the rootfs on my target, but I am wondering if it can be automated using buildroot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all take a look at [BR2_EXTERNAL mechanism](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#outside-br-custom). This way you can manage your project/configurations/package independent from Buildroot tree.

Then look at "Root filesystem overlays (BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY)" and "Post-build scripts (BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT)" in [Customizing the generated target filesystem](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#rootfs-custom) section. They describe both ways, i.e supply your custom file via fs-overlay or run a post-build script and alter the file within this script.

Comment: but BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT always run when I run make -j. causing duplicate line write to the file

Comment: @nuclear then your script will have to check if the change is already there or you just use the rootfs overlay.